# Adding Firebase leads to warning about mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes

Tags: android, firebase

On an **empty project**, after adding **firebase** it leads to the following **error**:

**Image Version :-**

[image: mixed version can lead to runtime crashes]

**Text Version :-**

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 25.2.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.2.0

**Another error :**

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'.

Is there any possible solution to remove those warnings?

My **project build.gradle** is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My **app build.gradle** is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mad.android.firebasetestauth2"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Before downvoting, it would have been great to know the reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error occurs because **google-services** is implementing some libraries, which are not using the 27.1.1 version. So we need to override the version.

In order to do so, always try to do run this in the ***terminal*** of android studio:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath
```

This will show you a list of dependencies, which shows the version number along it, something like this :-

[image: list of dependencies]

Here we need to find those dependencies whose haven't been overwritten and have a version number like **25 or 26 and not overwritten to 27**.

Like in the above example we have `com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0`

Now we just need to add this to the dependencies block with the up to date version number.

Finally, the **dependency block** looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Here we are adding

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
```

To fix the **second error** of

> WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'implementation' and 'api'.

In **project build.gradle**, update the

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```